# Prove that the condition number $c(A^k) \leq c(A)^k$ for every positive integer $k$ and invertible matrix A.

Tags: linear-algebra, condition-number

I'm not sure where to start here other than $c(A) = \| A \| \|A^{-1} \|$. How does this compare to $c(A^k)$?

Comment: What matrix norm are you using? It suffices to show that this norm is sub-multiplicative.

Comment: sorry I made that confusing with the same letter

Comment: [Your question should be clear without the title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/42969). After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We suppose that we work with a suborinate matrix norm $\Vert \cdot \Vert$, which satisfies the property
$$
\Vert A B \Vert \leq \Vert A \Vert \Vert B \Vert, \ \ 
\forall A, B \in \mathbf{R}^{n \times n} \tag{1}
$$

This can be easily generalized as
$$
\Vert A_1 A_2 \cdots A_k \Vert \leq \Vert A_1 \Vert
\Vert A_2 \Vert \cdots \Vert A_k \Vert, \ \
\forall A_1, A_2, \ldots, A_k \in \mathbf{R}^n \tag{2}
$$

If we take $A_1 = A_2 = \cdots = A_k = A$ in (2), we get
$$
\Vert A^k \Vert \leq \left( \Vert A \Vert \right)^k \tag{3}
$$

If we take $A_1 = A_2 = \cdots = A_k = A^{-1}$ in (2), we get
$$
\Vert \left( A^{-1} \right)^k \Vert \leq 
\left( \Vert A^{-1} \Vert \right)^k \tag{4}
$$

Let $\kappa(A)$ be the condition number of $A$ with respect to the subordinate matrix norm. Then by definition
$$
\kappa(A) = \Vert A \Vert \Vert A^{-1} \Vert
$$
and
$$
\kappa(A^k) = \Vert A^k \Vert \Vert \left( A^k \right)^{-1} \Vert
\leq \Vert A^k \Vert \ \Vert \left( A^k \right)^{-1} \Vert \tag{5}
$$

Using (3) and (4), we can simplify (5) as
$$
\kappa(A^k) \leq \left( \Vert A \Vert \right)^k 
 \left( \Vert A^{-1} \Vert \right)^k = 
\left( \Vert A \Vert \Vert A^{-1} \Vert \right)^k =
[ \kappa(A) ]^k
$$

This completes the proof. $\blacksquare$

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, why not look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements? Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.